# Array of strings in an API call,

Tags: json, api, rest, dart

Correct Answer below.

I want to select products by bulk instead of making individual product calls, but I'm just messing up the syntax and can't get the right combination even with all the answers here that I have read.

I am creating a list of product codes but keep getting back 404 or 405 error code

Instructions:
/products/bulk

```
productCodes
required
Array of strings <= 500 items
List of product codes for which to retrieve full product details
```

Request sample:

```
{
"productCodes": [
"5010SYDNEY",
"2050_PA",
"2855KENNEDY_TKTS"
]
}
```

My code:

```
// Product codes
const List productCodes = [
    '58109P2', '127269P1',
    '127269P1', '250556P1', '204123P16',       
  ];


try {
      var response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse("https://api.viator.com/partner/products/bulk?$productCodes"),
          headers: headers);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);    
        print(jsonData);

      }else{
            print(response.statusCode);

      }catch (e) {

      print(e);

      }
```

Access is fine,  I connect and can get the results back for a single product but it's the Array on string in the query that has me confused.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A couple of changes to get the page to load. The product codes have to be in a string

```
 var productCodes =
        '{"productCodes": ["58109P2","127269P1","250556P1"]}';
```

Then add them to a post call

```
var url = Uri.parse('https://api.viator.com/partner/products/bulk');
var response = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: productCodes);
```

The response then will have an instance of the object